# Mongoshell version conflicts - local mongod & mongod used by Mongolab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I've created a database on Mongolab that is running on the mongod version 3.0.7. 
I'm able to connect to the database from my local mongoshell as I'm using the same version, whereas my colleague is unable to as he is using version 3.0.6.

Do the versions need to be similar in order to connect ? If not, how can he connect without any issue?